# Mongoose: topology was destroyed MongoError

Tags: mongoose

We at https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone  have been doing the following in our e2e test server with no problem for a while now to drop databases before e2e starts:

`mongoose.connect(mongoUri,function(err){
        if (!err) {
            mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase(function (err) {
                mongoose.connection.close(function(err) {
                    done(err);
                })
            });
        } else {
            done(err);
        }
    });`

But as of recently (Mongoose 4.5.9) we now get the following errors at startup.  Any ideas?  Do we need to tweak the above drop db logic per some recent update?

`10:00:20:493 e2e: dropping test database
Mongoose model 'index-single-done' event fired on 'Boolean' for index:
 { key: 1 }
With error:
 topology was destroyed MongoError: topology was destroyed
    at Server.insert (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:1312:49)
    at Server.insert (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:351:17)
    at C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:1018:21
    at handleCallback (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:96:12)
    at C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:1697:20
    at handleCallback (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:96:12)
    at C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:306:20
    at commandCallback (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:1182:20)
    at Callbacks.flush (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:88:7)
    at Server.destroy (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:1075:41)
    at Server.close (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:398:17)
    at Db.close (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:357:19)
    at NativeConnection.doClose (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:233:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection._close (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:570:12)
    at C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:541:11
    at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$initializePromise (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\es6-promise\dist\es6-promise.js:409:9)
Mongoose model 'index' event fired on 'Boolean' with error:
 topology was destroyed MongoError: topology was destroyed
    at Server.insert (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:1312:49)
    at Server.insert (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:351:17)
    at C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:1018:21
    at handleCallback (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:96:12)
    at C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:1697:20
    at handleCallback (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:96:12)
    at C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:306:20
    at commandCallback (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:1182:20)
    at Callbacks.flush (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:88:7)
    at Server.destroy (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:1075:41)
    at Server.close (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:398:17)
    at Db.close (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:357:19)
    at NativeConnection.doClose (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:233:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection._close (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:570:12)
    at C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:541:11
    at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$initializePromise (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\es6-promise\dist\es6-promise.js:409:9)
Mongoose model 'index-single-done' event fired on 'CloudinaryImage' for index:
 { key: 1 }
With error:
 topology was destroyed MongoError: topology was destroyed
    at Server.insert (C:\Users\Carlos\git\prs\keystonejs\master\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:1312:49)
...`

Comment: update:  this now, very sporadically, seems to be happening during the test execution (not dropping the DB at that point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a logic error!  The screwy logic was initializing mongoose schema models, then dropping the database, then closing the database, then normal operations with the database.  For whatever reason, this worked for a long time without any errors.  Something probably got faster in performance until it caught up with synchronization issues leading to the errors described above.